# Render a template within def get_object instead of raise raise Http404

Tags: django, django-views

In the `get_object` method of class views, can I direct the user to a template instead of returning the object if an if statement fails?

Currently raise `Http404("Some message.")` works good but it doesn't look nice, I want to use my own template.

I'm trying to do this but with templates:

```
def get_object(self):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
    
        if product.deleted == False:
            if product.out_of_stock == False:
                return product
            else:
                raise Http404("This product is sold out.")
                # return reverse("404-error", kwargs={"error": "sold-out"})
                # return render(request, "custom_404.html", {"error": "sold_out"})
                                
        else:
            raise Http404("This product is no longer available.")
            # return reverse("404-error", kwargs={"error": "deleted"})
            # return render(request, "custom_404.html", {"error": "deleted"})
```

My main goal is to just avoid getting the object. I know I can perform the if statement in the `get_context_data` method, however I wasn't sure for objects containing sensitive data if there would be any way for a user to access it once it's in the `get_object`, so I just wanted to avoid getting the object altogether if the condition fails and display a template to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own view when a 404 error occurs, first create a custom view:

**views**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def handler404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, template_name='custom_404.html', status=404)
```

Now you need to override the default 404 view, adds this in your main `urls.py` file:

**urls.py**

```py
handler404 = 'appname.views.handler404'  # Replaces  appname with the name of the app that contains the custom view
```

Now you can simply raise a Http404 exception to show your custom template (you can keep your actual code).

Comment: Can I pass any context or kwargs to it? Like raise Http404("This product is no longer available.") or return render(request, template_name='custom_404.html', status=404, {"error": error2}). I need some way to differentiate different errors throughout the app.

Comment: I get it now, pass the same message but formatted with my custom view. I give you a tick because it makes sense but I can't test it. With debug off I get a 500 for some other reason and with debug on I can't see the template.